# testng.xml with classes works with packages not

Tags: java, xml, jar, testng

I have a question about testng.

1. I created **test classes in two packages**.
2. I created an **executable jar** (in eclipse) which **includes everything** (incl. the testng.jar, the testng.xml the compiled test classes,...
3. I **executed the jar** from commandline like so: `java -jar myTest.jar`

This works fine if I use concrete test classes in my testng.xml but does not if I use packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="all functional tests" parallel="classes" thread-count="10" verbose="1">

<!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
    <test name="exception path">
        <packages>
            <package name="com.MYFULLPACKAGEPATH.functional.exceptionPath.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>

<!-- WORKS -->
    <test name="failed tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.MYFULLPACKAGEPATH.functional.exceptionPath.FunctionalTest_TaskCreation_WithBadDueDateFormat" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Executing the tests unpackaged with ant works fine.

### Update

TestNG-XML-Suite-Execution is done in a starter class like this:

```
...
final InputStream is = Starter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlFileName);
final List<XmlSuite> suite = (List <XmlSuite>)(new Parser(is).parse());

testng.addListener(new EnhancedJunitReporter());
testng.setXmlSuites(suite);
        
testng.run();
...
```

Comment: Can you try removing .* in package value? You do not have specify wildcard to run all test in the package.

Comment: @Baski: THX for the try but: Same result. Total tests run: 0